# Centering Nested Divs on a Page Without Explicit Margin Values

Tags: css, html, css-position

I am trying to center a box element inside of the another element. I was able to accomplish this. However, I want to position both elements in the center of my page, without having to using explicit margin-left, margin-right values... and it is not working. Here's what I have:

```
    .Outer
    {            
        width: 1000px;
        height: 1000px;
        background-color: red;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
    }

    .Inner 
    {
        background-color: blue;
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        display: inline-block;     
    }
```

For some reason, when I try to set the Outer box to have a margin: 0 auto to center it, while having the `display: table-cell` set, the whole box moves to the left. That's not what I want. I tried to `float` the Outer then `clear: both`, but I just can't it in the center of my `body` element. What I am missing here? Is the only to achieve this by setting "some value" to top, left, right and margins explicitly, while I'm using `table-cell` on an element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi this will do the trick, I know you said no margins but it this will not affect anything even when you resize the page as you set left 50%

```
.Outer {            
   width: 1000px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -500px; /* HALF THE WIDTH OF THE ELEMENT YOU ARE CENTRING */
}
```

Comment: Yes, this helped out a lot. I had a feeling there was something odd to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/5sLsm08v/

Basically, just set the

```
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
```

in order to center the block.

Display "table-cell" doesn't work with margin 0 auto;

For testing purposes I used smaller dimensions of divs (100x50 instead of 1000x500).

If you don't want to have the divs centered vertically just remove the "vertical-align" :)